# Print values of %CPU over time for a particular process

Tags: top, cpu-usage

The [`top`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html) command gives information on running processes. The `%CPU` column gives the percentage of CPU each process is using (CPU usage).

Is there a simple way to print values of `%CPU` over *wall clock* time for a particular process (PID)?

Comment: What do you mean by "over time"? Over which time?

Comment: @aviro Good point! I mean over wall clock time. At 03:31:01, `%CPU` for the process was X%; at 03:31:02, `%CPU` for the process was Y%. I want to find X and Y.

Comment: You want to see those in real time, or you want to be able to see past values after the process already started? Meaning, do you just want to see how much CPU the procees consumed in total at the moment you check?

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want a 1 second granularity on the output? You can try the following:

```
PID=7101
while [[ -d /proc/$PID ]]
do
    ps u k-pcpu --noheaders -p $PID | awk '{print $3}'
    sleep 1
done
```

Timestamps can be added at will.