# Meaning of `u k-pcpu` options in ps

Tags: ps

In [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/687924/9605) to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/687899/), user @doneal24 suggests using, in part, the following call to `ps` to print information about the process with ID `PID`:

```
ps u k-pcpu -p $PID
```

According to `ps`'s [`man` page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html), the `u` option, in the section "output format control," indicates to display user-oriented format.

But what does `k-pcpu` indicate?

- Is `k` the `k` code for `utime`/"user time" listed in the "Obselete Sort Keys" section of the [`man` page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html)?
- Is `-pcpu` related to the `pcpu` code listed in the "Standard Format Specifiers" section of the [`man` page?](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html)